# basic for loop problems in python

Tags: python, for-loop

this is a really easy coding problem, I haven't coded since highschool, and I am super rusty! I'm probably missing something super obvious. I get an invalid syntax error on the for line of the code, an I don't understand why.. how can I get this simple code to work? what am I doing wrong?

```
p=1
a=p+60
p = p+6*2/2*45
if (p == 271):
    p=3000


print ("this is p:")
print (p)
print ("this is a")
print (a)
for ( p > a ):
        p=p-1
        print (p)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using a `for` loop when you should be using a `while` loop. A `for` loop will loop through an iterable object or collection and a `while` loop will continue as long as a condition is True. Also the parentheses are not need for `if` and `for`:

```
p=1
a=p+60
p = p+6*2/2*45
if p == 271:
    p=3000


print ("this is p:")
print (p)
print ("this is a")
print (a)
while p > a :
        p=p-1
        print (p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `for` construct is logically equivalent to the `foreach` construct in many other languages; in other words, it is for iterating over the items in an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

From your code, it looks like you are trying to keep iterating as long as the condition `p > a` holds true. In Python, this is a situation where you would want to use a `while` loop:

```py
while p > a:
    p = p - 1
    print(p)
```

Note also that you don't need parentheses around the condition, unlike in some other languages.